# How can I improve the following Python code to fit pseudo-Voigt profile to asymmetric peak?

Tags: python, analytics, distribution

I would like to fit a pseudo-Voigt profile to an asymmetric curve in order to determine the FWHM. I tried to follow the mathematical method laid out in a paper (DOI: 10.1039/c8an00710a) which outlines the how to modify a pseudo-Voigt fitting to include a permutation that introduces asymmetry for Raman spectroscopy.

I can't seem to get it right.

My attempt is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def wavenumber_dependent_fwhm(omega, Gamma_0, a, omega_0):
    return 2 * Gamma_0 / (1 + np.exp(a * (omega - omega_0)))

def lorentzian_distribution(omega, A, Gamma, omega_0):
    return A / (2 * np.pi) * (Gamma / ((omega - omega_0) ** 2 - (Gamma / 2) ** 2))

def gaussian_distribution(omega, A, Gamma, omega_0):
    return A / Gamma * np.sqrt(4 * np.log(2) / np.pi) * np.exp(-4 * np.log(2 * ((omega - omega_0) / Gamma) ** 2))

def perturbation_damped_sigmoidal(omega, a, Gamma, omega_0):
    return 1 - (a * (omega - omega_0) / Gamma) * np.exp(-((omega - omega_0) ** 2) / (2 * (2 * Gamma) ** 2))

def FWHM(Gamma_0, a):
    return Gamma_0 * (1 + 0.40 * a ** 2 + 1.35 * a **4)

# Define the pseudo-Voigt profile function with parameters
def pseudo_voigt_profile_params(omega, params):
    a, m, Gamma, omega_0, amplitude, baseline = params
    gauss_term = gaussian_distribution(omega * perturbation_damped_sigmoidal(omega, a, Gamma, omega_0), 1, Gamma, 0)
    lorentzian_term = lorentzian_distribution(omega * perturbation_damped_sigmoidal(omega, a, Gamma, omega_0), 1, Gamma, 0)
    return m * gauss_term + (1 - m) * lorentzian_term

# Define the residual function to minimize (difference between data and model)
def residual(params, omega, intensity):
    return pseudo_voigt_profile_params(omega, params) - intensity

# Load data from the CSV file
data = np.loadtxt('data_file.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=5)  # Adjust path and skiprows as needed

# Extract omega and intensity from the data
omega_values = data[:, 0]
intensity_values = data[:, 1]

# Initial guesses for parameters [a, m, Gamma, omega_0, amplitude, baseline]
initial_guesses = [0, 3E-139, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

# Perform the fit using least squares
result = least_squares(residual, initial_guesses, args=(omega_values, intensity_values))

# Extract the optimized parameters
optimized_params = result.x

# Generate the fitted pseudo-Voigt profile using the optimized parameters
fit_profile = pseudo_voigt_profile_params(omega_values, optimized_params)

# Plot the original data and the fitted pseudo-Voigt profile
plt.plot(omega_values, intensity_values, label='Experimental Data')
plt.plot(omega_values, fit_profile, label='Fitted Pseudo-Voigt Profile')
plt.xlabel('Omega')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print('Optimized Parameters:')
print('a:', optimized_params[0])
print('m:', optimized_params[1])
print('Gamma:', optimized_params[2])
print('omega_0:', optimized_params[3])
print('Amplitude:', optimized_params[4])
print('Baseline:', optimized_params[5])
```

The output is a plot of the data and the 'fitted' pseudo-Voigt

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaF6c.png)

Comment: Since this code works, maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be more helpful? Just read their [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page first.